# Scoring rules for Dirichlet process mixtures

Tags: stochastic-processes, scoring-rules, dirichlet-process

Let's say I do a sample-based fitting of a Dirichlet process model:
$$
\begin{aligned}
X_i &\sim f(x_i\mid \theta_i)\\
\theta_i &\sim G\\
G &\sim \text{DP}(\alpha, G_0)
\end{aligned}
$$
where I'm fitting cluster assignment by MCMC.  Let's introduce a latent parameter $\delta_i$ that indicates cluster assignment.

$$
P(\delta_i = j) \propto \begin{cases}
n_j^{-i}f(x_i\mid\theta_j) & \text{for }j = 1,\ldots,J^{-i}\\
\alpha\int_{\Omega}f(x_i\mid\theta_i)dG_0(\theta_i)d\theta_i &\text{for }j = J^{-i} + 1
\end{cases}
$$

Let's say I want to evaluate my fitted model using a scoring rule.  Let's say, posterior predictive loss (Gelfand and Ghosh):

$$
S = Var(X_i) + \frac{k}{k+1}\left(x_i - \text{E}(X_i)\right)^2
$$

Where both expectations are taken  with respect to the posterior predictive distribution.

Do I use the posterior predictive distribution assuming the fitted $\delta_i$'s, or is $\text{E}(X_i)$ with respect to a *new* $X_i$?

I've been doing the former, and I'm now having doubts.  Take a hypothetical example: binary data, with a mixture on point masses at 1 and 0--if I'm allowed to factor the fitted mixture identifiers into the calculation for score, then I will always result in a perfect model, predicting with 0 error and zero variance.  I believe this is wrong.  Am I correct in this interpretation?

Comment: Yes, the former is incorrect. You should use new $X_i$, although I don't have a source.

Comment: You might also consider using generic clustering metrics e.g. Rand scores, mutual information, normalized mutual information, etc. sklearn has these already implemented.

Comment: Either way, these metrics are useful for performing model comparison, meaning you need competitor probabilistic models or competitor inference algorithms or both. The posterior predictive probability doesn't mean anything in any absolute sense.

Comment: I have several candidate models---various structures for the centering distribution, prior assumptions, whether to restrict one of the parameters of the kernel distribution.

A source would be really nice.  Looking at the Gelfand and Ghosh paper, they mention the squared bias term as $x_i - \mu_i$, where $\mu_i = \text{E}[X_i \mid X_{\text{obs}}]$... which includes $x_i$.

Comment: The [Gneiting and Rafferty paper](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/raftery/Research/PDF/Gneiting2007jasa.pdf) that I'm also using mentions $E(X_i\mid x_i)$, which is tremendously frustrating.   It effectively *invites* using the fitted $\delta_i$'s to do the cluster identification.  I can't tell what's right.  Logic says my first method is wrong, but aside from my simple example, I can't say *why* it's wrong.